# Transform pseudo-element based on parent

Tags: css, css-transforms, pseudo-element

I'm making a Material Design web app, and I made it so that the drawer is only one element using a `:before` pseudo-element to make the scrim (to darken the background and bring the drawer to prominence).

```
#app-bar-drawer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 85%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1200;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  transition: opacity .1s, transform .3s;
}

#app-bar-drawer.in {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

#app-bar-drawer:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  width: 10000%;
  transform: translateX(350px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  z-index: 700;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #app-bar-drawer:before {
    transform: translateX(350px); /* this is what I can't figure out */
  }
}
```

On larger phones, tablets, desktops, etc this works fine:
[image]

As you can see, the scrim is positioned at the edge of the drawer and covers the content neatly. However, with smaller devices, it moves too far and looks like this:
[image]

In this one, the scrim is at the far right edge of the screen, as the `transform: translateX(350px)` is pushing it too far. I've tried changing it to use a percentage, but percentages are of the `:before` pseudo-element, not the parent. When I tried using a pixel measure like `200px`, it would either go too far (and wouldn't cover the content) or too close (and cover the drawer).

**SUMMARY**

I can't use either percentages or pixel measures. I'd rather do this without JS, but if necessary I'll do it. Is this possible? It needs to be a single element.

Comment: Would you be able to share a minimal demo of the issue? It would be easier to help, thanks

Comment: Hange on... it'll take a few minutes

Comment: @sol, https://tricksfortheweb.com/writer/

Comment: Would you consider adding the pseudoelement to the body? Make it full width and remove transformations. Ensure that the menu has a higher z-index and it should be fine. Toggle a class on the body when the menu is toggled.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Put it in an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to toggle the psueodoelement on the body when the menu is toggled. You can set it to the full width of the viewport using `position: fixed` and coordinates, which avoids dealing with transformations.

Ensure the `z-index` of the menu is higher than the psuedoelement.